# What is causing this failure when using readHTMLTable()?

Tags: xml, excel, r

```
library(XML)
url <- 'http://www.dqnews.com/Charts/Monthly-Charts/LA-Times-Charts/ZIPLAT.aspx'
tableVals <- readHTMLTable(url)
```

When I run this all by itself on a fresh workspace, I get

```
Error: Namespace prefix  of attribute publishsource is not defined
```

After digging through the page source, the closest attribute I found to the one in the error is this:

```
`<div id="Chart for Web_9726" align="center" x:publishsource="Excel">`
```

but searching turns up nothing.  Is there perhaps a better way to automatically vacuum this data into a matrix or dataframe?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; it ran for me and return a data frame with the values in it.

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my machine. Please give more information about your setup, e.g. OS, R version, etc. Tip: paste the results of `sessionInfo()` into your question.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it myself now, but rather I get "Error in htmlParse(doc): error in creating parser for http://www.dqnews.com/Charts/Monthly-Charts/LA-TImes-Charts/ZIPLAT.aspx"